# An efficient way to assign user_ids to huge dataset under certain conditions

Tags: algorithm, postgresql

I have a dataset contains pairs of tx_ids and node_ids where every tx_id is associated with one or more node_id.
The node_ids that are connected to the same tx_id belong to the same user.
And if the same node_id is connected to different tx_ids then all  nodes associated with these tx_ids belong to the same user as well.

Take a look at the following small sample of the dataset:

```
tx_id       node_id         user_id
1               a               1
1               d               1
```

---

```
2               d               1
2               g               1
```

---

```
3               g               1
3               e               1
```

---

```
4               c               2
4               f               2
```

For example, nodes {a,d} belong to the same user as they appear with the same tx_id. Additionally, {d} is connected to tx_ids = {1, 2} then {a, d, g} all belong to the same user. But {g} appears in tx_ids = {2, 3}, that means all nodes in tx_ids = {1,2,3} belong to the same user (as illustrated above).

Lets put it this way:
tx_id= transaction_id, and node_id =bank account.

A user may have multiple bank accounts, and the bank account belongs to one and only one user. Now user can originate a single transaction from different accounts (in my situation), 
so in the above example for tx_id =1, (User_1) used the two accounts {a,d}, which means that any transaction that used accounts {a,d} belongs to User_1, consequently tx_id=2  belongs to User_1 since it contains account {d} which appeared in tx_id =1. I want to create a new table which has tx_id, node_id, user_id(new integer value, not continuous and not unique)

The problem is that in my dataset the user_ids are not assigned to nodes and I have a huge dataset of 400M records. I am looking for an efficient way to solve this, given that my dataset is stored in PostgreSQL database. If it is possible to solve this by SQL queries, that would be great, otherwise, any suggestion in any programming language is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And wat exactly is your goal? Detecting (groups of) nodes that "belong to" exactly on user?

Comment: In other words: please add a question to your question.

Comment: If a bank account belongs to exactly one user, there will be an Functional Dependency bank-account -> user.

Comment: I only have the tx_ids(transactions) and the node_ids(bank accounts) they use. I don't have the mapping between these transactions or/and accounts and users using them. This is what I am trying to do

Comment: Looks like `SELECT DISTINCT user_id, node_id FROM tx_table;`

Comment: The user_id column doesn’t exist I added it for illustration. I want to create a new table which has tx_id, node_id, user_id(new integer value, not continuous and not unique)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use python dictionary as a lookup table to store node_ids and their corresponding user_ids. Retrieve tx_id, node_id list ordered by tx_id, and if a node_id appeared with two tx_ids, the tx which comes later will find that the node_id already stored in python dictionary and get the user_id from dict.

This is union-find partitioning problem, the question is how to unite sets(tx in your case) if they have a common node_id.